# Android SQLITE Illegal State Exception

Tags: android, sqlite, illegalstateexception

I am using the following code to add items to the Database :

```
public static void insertQuestion(Context c,JSONArray jarr,String search) throws JSONException {
        DatabaseWrapper databaseWrapper = new DatabaseWrapper(c);
        SQLiteDatabase database = databaseWrapper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = postToContentValues2(jarr);
        values.put(QuestionORM.COLUMN_SEARCH,search);
        long questionId = database.insert(QuestionORM.TABLE_NAME, "null", values);
        Log.e(TAG, "Inserted new Question with ID: " + questionId);
        database.close();
    }
```

But I get an error saying

> "attempt to re-open an already-closed object"

on this line :

```
SQLiteDatabase database = databaseWrapper.getWritableDatabase();
```

How do I resolve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Post the full stacktrace and your sqlite helper `onCreate()` / `onUpgrade()` callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check before open it

```
if(database != null && database.isOpen()){
// if open then don't open
}
```

---- UPDATE ----

// add this method in your class calss

```
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

...

    public boolean isDatabaseOpened() {
        if (myDataBase == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return myDataBase.isOpen();
    }
```

if method returns false then only call getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabas() as per your requirement.

Comment: Can you explain further in context to my question? Where exactly do I put this ? Above the second line ?

Comment: you have object databaseWrapper right? and override method in databaseWrapper class add my code in it.

Comment: But databaseWrapper doesn't have a method called isOpen() ?

Comment: @ShivamBhalla please check upate.

Comment: Yes this solves the problem. Though I am still unable to add items. The Log shown here is never displayed. Why is that ?

Comment: post log if you getting any problme

Comment: No there are no errors. I am just not getting any data in the database.