# Android SQLite data is not being added

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am using the following code to add JSON Arrays to SQLite database :

QuestionORM Class :

```
public static void insertQuestion(Context c,JSONArray jarr,String search) throws JSONException {
    DatabaseWrapper databaseWrapper = new DatabaseWrapper(c);
    if(isDatabaseOpened())
    {
        myDataBase = databaseWrapper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = postToContentValues2(jarr);
        values.put(QuestionORM.COLUMN_SEARCH,search);
        long questionId = myDataBase.insert(QuestionORM.TABLE_NAME, "null", values);
        Log.e(TAG, "Inserted new Question with ID: " + questionId);
        myDataBase.close();
    }
}

private static ContentValues postToContentValues2(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject job1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        if(job1!=null)
        {
            JSONObject job2 = job1.getJSONObject("owner");
            values.put(QuestionORM.COLUMN_ID, job1.getString("question_id"));
            values.put(QuestionORM.COLUMN_TITLE,job1.getString("title"));
            values.put(QuestionORM.COLUMN_AUTHOR,job2.getString("display_name"));
            values.put(QuestionORM.COLUMN_VOTES,job1.getString("score"));
        }
    }
    return values;
}

public static boolean isDatabaseOpened() {
    if (myDataBase == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return myDataBase.isOpen();
}
```

This is used like this in another activity :

```
        QuestionORM.insertQuestion(MainActivity.this,mJSONArr,url);
```

However, the log is never displayed, and the database is empty. I don't get any errors in my logcat either.

What is wrong ? How do I fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No. No error like I said

Comment: `long questionId = myDataBase.insert(QuestionORM.TABLE_NAME, null, values);` null is not a string

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain I removed the quotes, but the issue persists.

Comment: you say the log is not showing, does it show anything at all (even if they are from other apps)?

Comment: Yes it shows the usual information, debug messages etc. Just not the log for db insertion.

Answer (score -1):

You define a the following method:

```
public static boolean isDatabaseOpened() {
    if (myDataBase == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return myDataBase.isOpen();
}
```

you're using [myDatabase.isOpen()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#isOpen()) and according to the documentation, it returns:

> True if the database is currently open (has not been closed).

However, your `insertQuestion()` method does close the database.

[**UPDATE**]

Do not close the database at the end of the `insertQuestion()` method. You should rather do that on the `onDestroy` method. Open it once, in `onCreate` method and close it when you no longer need it.

Comment: Yes, but I am calling this method before I close the database. That method is to check whether the DB is open or not .

Comment: remove the `isDatabaseOpened() ` check. why would the db be open by default (on  the first run, that is)?

Comment: Yes I had done that previously but was facing an error. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961755/android-sqlite-illegal-state-exception

Comment: I tried the edit and removed the close() function call, but I still don't get any data in the database.